# Request external Variables using Jquery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am building a simple HTML page that makes a get request and passes variables to a PHP file.

I statically set the variables in a script on the HTML page and pass them to the PHP file using jquery.

It currently works without issue.

I would like to be able to store the variables in an external file js,php,txt it doesnt matter just so someone couldn't view source and see the variables.

For Example

```
var name="myname"
var address ="myaddress"
```

How can I make a simple get request to store those values in a separate file and store them in variables for the script on my html page?

Comment: XML would probably be a good file type for local storage, although a database is preferred in my opinion

Comment: [Security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not secure.  A user will be able to see these variables whether they are in the page source or retrieved later and added dynamically as variables.  If you really want them to be hidden from the user, they must be kept on the server and not sent to the client in any plain-text form.  That being said, you could send the variables encrypted and use your PHP script to decrypt them.

Comment: Or you could send your PHP variables as sessions in the background, where the user won't see them. See my answer where I explained how sessions work. Once you understand the basics, you can easily implement them into your code in the way that you need. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth looking into the php `$_SESSION` variable. This variable can pass from page to page, making it easy to store information in the background, without people being able to view the data stored in the variable.

Here is a quick example of this variable in action:

#### Set.php

session_start(); //start the session to recieve and set variables

```
$_SESSION['myvar'] = "Hello world!";
```

#### Call.php

session_start();

```
echo $_SESSION['myvar']; //outputs the variable set on set.php
```

PHP sessions are an in-depth topic, and there is so much you can do with them. I highly recomend looking at this manual reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

In this example, I echoed out the data in the session **however this is completely optional**, you can pass this data in the background, and just use it for backend work as well. The only way that the user can see the data stored in the session is if it is echoed out to the page.

I hope this gives you a boost in the right direction! Let me know if you have further questions :)

Comment: Session is a good idea but you should rewrite your answer to avoid sending the variable in the server's response to comply with the OP requirements: *"someone couldn't view source and see the variables"*.

Comment: @PrestonS please read the second sentence of my answer. It is not possible for a user to view the data stored in a session from the client side.

Comment: @PrestonS you are right, you most definitely can read this data _if it is echoed_. But the point of this demonstration was to show how the variables pass, obviously it is optional to echo the data. You are picking a stupid argument here, as the answer is clearly to demonstrate how the sessions work, not how to only use them in the background. Please refer to the part of the answer where it says "Here is an example of these variables in action". Clearly, i am just demonstrating how the session vars work, and I am echoing to prove that the data, did in fact, pass to the new page. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer "is not useful" simply for the fact that your example code fails to adhere to the one simple requirement set by the OP.  Just change your code sample a little to be more relevant to the OP and this will be a good and right answer.  That is all.

Comment: @PrestonS I'm not about to go post the entire program that he needs, as that is against stackoverflow rules. All that I am trying to do is boost him in the right direction. Please see my edit, maybe you will see what I mean if your brain can handle a few sentences ;)